# Add libraries to GDAL

Tags: postgresql, postgis, gdal

I've been reading through the documentation and I'm having a hard time finding where and how to add libraries to a PostGIS install with GDAL support, installed from a windows binary packager. I'm importing an NITF file with an embedded JPEG2000 image within. the error reads

```
ERROR 1: Unable to open JPEG2000 within NITF file.
No JPEG2000 capable driver (JP2KAK JP2EECW JP2MRSID etc...) is availale.
```

You can define the NITF_OPENUNDERLYING_DS configuration option to NO, in order to just get the metadata.

It also doesn't state how to set that configuration. Because I would much rather have the metadata for this stage of my project. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What actual command are you running?

Comment: raster2pgsql -I -C -M (FILENAME).ntf -F -t auto public.demelevation | psql -d ddf -U ddf

Comment: How did you install Postgis, from a package, from source?

Comment: windows binary package

Comment: I have updated your post to include Windows -- sorry, I'm a linux user, so can't help with gdal/postgis binary installs.  Could you clarify what this means: "I'm importing an NITF file with an embedded within the error reads". I think there is a word missinge after embedded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many GDAL installations don't include J2K support.  Before loading NITF's, I would try a normal j2k file (.jp2).  That will tell you for sure.  If no support is included, I would consider just building it from source.

With GDAL, you have several options for a J2K reader.  Usually, I use OpenJPEG as it seems to build easier in Windows for me.  Otherwise, you can use Jasper.  Kakadu is a good library, but it is not free.

Luckily, the nmake Makefile is really clean.  You should need to tweak only the config file beforehand (nmake.opt).  I would build Proj4 and OpenJpeg with it.

Finally, here are the NITF driver docs in GDAL if that has what you are looking for...

http://www.gdal.org/frmt_nitf.html